# System does not boot after setting Display Name for main root partition

Tags: automount, disk-management

I tried to make all of my NTFS drives auto-mount. I only checked "Mount at startup" for all NTFS drived. Meanwhile, I set "Display Name" for all NTFS drive and my only Ext4 partition (where `/` is mounted.)

[image]

Unfortunately, after resetting, the following message is displayed and the system does boot to X window.

```
Press S to skip mounting or M for manual Recovery
```

What is wrong with it?

Here the content of fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01CFF42B661F4490 /mnt/01CFF42B661F4490 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01CFF42B6AD7C390 /mnt/01CFF42B6AD7C390 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Ketabxune 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01CFF42B6F86CCB0 /mnt/01CFF42B6F86CCB0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Rasune 0 0
UUID=727266ee-c859-4d70-add9-19c20ab5606a / defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/A40E6CED0E6CBA46 /mnt/A40E6CED0E6CBA46 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data 0 0
```

Here is the output of `fsck /` command:

```
error 3 while executing fsck.defaults for /dev/sda8
mountall: fsck / [777] terminating  with status 8
mountall: Unrecoverable fsck error: /
```

Comment: I typically place automounted partitions in /etc/fstab. You may find this helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions (Disks is buggy)

Comment: Plese [edit] your question to include the results of attempting **M**anual Recovery

Comment: at the command prompt from Manual Recovery you need to fsck your root and possibly home partitions.

Comment: The error indicates that the device doesn't exist. This may be related to this rare bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/712811 Try booting from a live CD and running fsck on /dev/sda8 from there.

Comment: Also in order for sda8 to be valid, this must be a GPT partition. Please add the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` to your question. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do the opposite of what you expect.

The toggle for Auto-mount in Disks is broken. For some reason on is off and off is on. As you can see here is my auto-mount options for an NTFS partition. Note that it's set to OFF

[image: automount options]

But it appears labelled properly in nautilus under devices with the display name of fubar and is accessible

[image: auto-mount device]

I've opened a bug that you and other affected users can subscribe to [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1463159)

A also recommend you change the options in your fstab for your root partition to

/               ext4    **errors=remount-ro 0       1**

You may also find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123963/how-to-force-fsck-at-every-boot-all-relevant-filesystems) helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `cat /etc/fstab`